# Postgresql row to json as array of values (without keys)

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I'm trying to map the results of a query to JSON in PostgreSQL.

I can do the mapping with the following query:

`select row_to_json(t) from (select * from mytable) t;`

For example, let the table 'mytable' contains three columns and three records, then the query can return:

```
{"first":11,"second":12,"third":13}
{"first":21,"second":22,"third":23}
{"first":31,"second":32,"third":33}
```

The query above returns each row as a JSON object. But all the keys will be the same for each row.

I want to get only values as JSON array like that:

```
[11,12,13]
[21,22,23]
[31,32,33]
```

How can I do that efficiently in PostgreSQL?...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json_build_array()` - but it requires enumerating the column names:

```
select json_build_array(first, second, third) res
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ff35bd37a84bb4b26be39f01a03d7c95)**:

```
| res          |
| :----------- |
| [11, 12, 13] |
| [21, 22, 23] |
| [31, 32, 33] |
```